# Twitter Bootstrap & OpenLayers Shrinking Map by 100px

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, gis, openlayers

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and Open Layers to show a map on a page:

http://tinypic.com/r/2qu826t/5

The map should be 100 pixels to the left and over top of the div `id="OpenLayers.Layer.Image_84"` (outlined in blue).

It should also be 1024 pixels wide; instead it's been truncated to about 823.

The results can be seen in the div containing the map tile (a 1024x1024 png):

`<img class="olTileImage" style="visibility: inherit; opacity: 1; position: absolute; left: 101%; top: 0%; width: 822.944%; height: 1024%;" src="/static/img/maps/seattle.png"`

If I manually change `left:101%` to `left:1%` and `width:822.944%` to `width:1024%` everything looks right. But I've no idea what is programmatically causing this to be wrong.

Also, I've used the exact same code in a non-Bootstrap sandbox and it works fine. Hence my assumption that it's a collision with Bootstrap that's causing this.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem only occurs with Openlayers 2.12. Try add this css code:

```
.olMapViewport img {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks; turns out the error was trying to fit a square image tile to non-square bounds. The ~10% gap between the square image tile and the rectangular space caused this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So this was not a collision between Bootstrap and OpenLayers but incorrectly fitting a square map tile to rectangular bounds.

Here's an overview:
1) I set the map size to square
2) I set the map bounds to what I thought was a square, but actually a rectangle with ~80% the width of a square

OpenLayers tried to reconcile these by adding the `left` attribute and compressing the map tile.

When I properly set the map bounds to a square, the issue disappeared.

Comment: The OL team will release in a few days the version 2.13, which does not use percentages... no more worrying about this.